# Extracting a feature by feature name in scikit dict vectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a List of dictionaries which I convert to vectorial represenation using the `DictVectorizer` in `scikit-learn`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()
dictvector = D = [{'foo': 'city1', 'bar': 2, 'label':'c1'}, {'foo': 'city2', 'baz': 1, 'label':'c2'}]
dictVector = vec.fit_transform(dictList)
```

Now, from each row I want to extract the values of all the tuples for feature 'label' and then remove them from the vectors. This will help to use the vectors as input for Decision tree classifier in `scikit` and the corresponding labels as ground truth for the classifier.

But when I tried with calling the feature name as a dictionary key. I am asked to use only integer and not strings. How can the same be resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Features with `DictVectorizer` are mapped to [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays, which represents the feature as `NxM` numerical matrix (dictionary is lost). However, the class `DictVectorizer` preserves the mapping function internally, and you can recover it using `.inverse_transform`. From the documentation of  [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
>>> D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
>>> X = v.fit_transform(D)
>>> X
array([[ 2.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.]])
>>> v.inverse_transform(X) == [{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'baz': 1.0, 'foo': 3.0}]
True
```

Thus, for a single instance `x_i` (row) belonging to `X`, you can recover the mapping as:

```
>>> v.inverse_transform(X[i][None, :])
```

The last bit `[None, :]` converts the `M` length row `X[i]` in a `1xM` row vector. Is not entirely needed, but scikits-learn throws a warning. The following should also work:

```
>>> v.inverse_transform(X[i])
```

---

Now, answering the question, to remove a given feature from your data `X`, `DictVectorizer` also stores the name corresponding to every feature in `feature_names_`.

```
>>> v.feature_names_
['bar', 'baz', 'foo']
```

Thus, you could do something like:

```
>>> column = v.feature_names_.index('foo') # Column mapping index of key 'foo'
>>> values = X[:, column] # get values
>>> X[:, column] = 0 # remove them from X
```

---

Last, extending the answer to sparse matrices with `DictVectorizer(sparse=True)` where `X` now is a NxM sparse matrix instead of a numpy array. The above solution works with minor modifications (note `.todense()` in the value extraction):

```
>>> column = v.feature_names_.index('foo')
>>> values = X[:, column].todense() # get values
>>> X[:, column] = 0 # remove them from X
```

Replace `'foo'` by `'label'` in the above code to make it work for you.

Comment: `DictVectorizer` has the method `get_feature_names()` which might be safer than accessing the `feature_names_` attribute directly.